# Proving that $\Gamma (x) = \int_{0}^{1} \left( \ln \left(\frac{1}{u} \right) \right)^{x-1} du$

Tags: integration, analysis, gamma-function

I want to prove that
$$
\Gamma (x) = \int_{0}^{1} \left( \ln  \left(\frac{1}{u} \right)  \right)^{x-1} du
$$

I start with 
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \left( \ln  \left(\frac{1}{u} \right)  \right)^{x-1} du =
$$

$$
\int_{0}^{1} \left( -\ln u  \right)^{x-1} du  
$$

Now, if I set $-\ln u = t$, I have $u=e^{-t}$ and $dt=\frac{-du}{u} \Leftrightarrow du = -dt * u. $

I will set these to my function above:

$$
 \int_{0}^{1} t^{x-1}(-e^{t})(-dt) =  \int_{0}^{1} t^{x-1}e^{t}dt
$$

Which is like the $\Gamma =  \int_{0}^{+\infty} t^{x-1}e^{t}dt$, except for the ends.

How do I change the 1 into $+\infty$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change integration limits when doing the change of variable!

Comment: So I just change them then and set it to $\int_{0}^{+\infty}$ without any further explanation?

Comment: Yes. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution.